# Time dependent perturbation theory

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I'm studying time dependent perturbation theory on Reed-Simon book "Method of modern mathematical physics, II". If one considers an Hamiltonian of the form
$$H(t)=H_0+V(t)$$
the corresponding formal propagator is given by
$$U(t,s)=e^{-itH_0}\tilde{U}(t,s)e^{isH_0}\,,$$
where $\tilde{U}(t,s)$ is the propagator associated to $\tilde{V}
(t)=e^{iH_0t}V(t)e^{isH_0}$.
How to prove that if $t\to [H_0,V(t)]$ is strongly continuous, then $U(t,s)$ is the actual propagator for $H(t)$? Any suggestions?